# httpAccessor.HttpContext.SignInAsync User is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor-pages

## Context

I have one web application seperated in two "utilities".

1. Web API
2. Razor Pages

So my app is both an API and a ASP.NET Razor Pages app, to authenticate on the Web API side I use JWT Bearer and on Web App side a simple Cookie.

## Problem

When using Cookie Authentication, I followed Microsoft's [Use cookie authentication without ASP.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and it's absolutely not working AT ALL.

I use a custom AuthManager with a SignInAsync method. The cookie is indeed created BUT the ClaimsPrincipal in my HttpContext is empty

I didn't find ANY SOLUTION AT ALL on internet, the only solutions that seemed viable were by using custom Middlewares but I don't even know where to start.

If anybody encountered the same problem as me.

Thanks

```cs
public async Task<bool> LogInAsync(string email, string password, bool rememberMe)
        {
            UserModel user = _userService.UserLogin(email, password).MapFromBLL();
            if (user is null) return false;

            user.Roles = _roleService.GetUserRoles(user.Id).Select(r => r.MapFromBLL());
            if (user.Roles is null || user.Roles.Count() == 0) return false;

            List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>()
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Email),
                new Claim("Stamp", user.SecurityStamp.ToString())
            };

            IEnumerable<Claim> roleClaims = user.Roles.Select(ur => new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, ur.Name));

            claims.AddRange(roleClaims);

            ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            AuthenticationProperties authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                AllowRefresh = true,
                ExpiresUtc = DateTime.Now.AddDays(_jwtModel.ExpirationInDays),
                IsPersistent = true,
                IssuedUtc = DateTime.Now,
            };

            ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);

            try
            {
                await _httpAccessor.HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, claimsPrincipal, authProperties);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Startup.cs

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
                .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
                 {
                     options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                     options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                     options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.None;
                     options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
                     options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
                     options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
                     options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Forbidden";
                     options.EventsType = typeof(SecurityStampUpdatedCookieAuthenticationEvent);
                 })
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                    {
                        ValidIssuer = jwtModel.Issuer,
                        ValidAudience = jwtModel.Audience,
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jwtModel.Secret)),
                        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                    };
                });
```

### EDIT 10-02-2022

I seperated the post in two chapters : "Context" and "Problem"

Comment: "The cookie is indeed created BUT the ClaimsPrincipal in my HttpContext is empty". Where in your code are you trying to access the ClaimsPrincipal? Are you doing it as part of the current (login) request or are you redirecting after login and then trying to read the User?

Comment: After the connection, so after the method LogInAsync is executed, I redirect to Index page in which I have `@User.Name` that displayes but it didn't, after debugging and checking step after step, I saw that `_httpAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity` is empty.

Comment: I updated my post so you have a context

Comment: Great. Thank you for adding more info. Are you executing the `LoginAsync` method on the WebAPI side or the ASP.NET side?

Comment: Meaning, are you doing the login as part of a WebAPI call and then redirecting on the client side? Or are you actually posting to the ASP.NET side, executing the login and then redirecting server side?

Comment: In my Web API side I generate a Jwt Token but on ASP.NET Side I generate a Cookie. I posted my solution if you are interested, it works perfectly fine for the moment. Thanks for the reply :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## My solution

Ok, so I found a solution to my problem. It was, as usual after 10 hours of research, dumb. In my **Startup.cs** I used **JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme** as **DefaultAuthenticateScheme**. So I changed it with **CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme**, and now by miracle IT WORKS. After logging in, my **ClaimsPrincipal** User is full and it retrieve correctly the cookie.

My new `services.AddAuthentication()` in **Startup.cs**

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
```

I don't really know if I should keep  `options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;`. If anyone could enlight me.

I didn't change anything in my method `public async Task<bool> SignInAsync()` I just added `await _httpAccessor.HttpContext.SignOutAsync()` at the beginning just to be sure.

```cs
public async Task<bool> LogInAsync(string email, string password, bool rememberMe)
        {
            await LogOutAsync();

            // The same code as before
        }
```

The `LogOutAsync()` method

```cs
public async Task LogOutAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                await _httpAccessor.HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

## Problems encountered

### Authorization

After fixing this problem, I had another one. Now that my default scheme is Cookie based, I can't just use `[Authorize]` and except it to work with both Cookie or Jwt. To fix that I just added this code in **Startup.cs** after `services.AddAuthentication()`

```cs
AuthorizationPolicy multiSchemePolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultPolicy = multiSchemePolicy;
            });
```

Code that I found [here](https://www.dominikzoechbauer.com/blog/2021-02-20/combining-and-cookie-jwt-bearer-authentication/#defining-the-multi-scheme-policy)

### API Unauthorize return Login Page instead of 401 or 403 status codes

This one is kind of strange, now the cookie and the JwtBearer worked fine, when I tried to access an `[Authorize]` route, sometimes it returned me the HTML page to Login instead of **401 Status Code** and sometimes not.

To avoid this problem, I found a solution [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/9039#issuecomment-479667297)

using `services.ConfigureApplicationCookie` didn't work for me, instead I adapted my `services.AddCookie()`.

```cs
.AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
                 {
                     options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
                     options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Forbidden";

                     options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents()
                     {
                         OnRedirectToLogin = (ctx) =>
                         {
                             if (ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api") && ctx.Response.StatusCode == 200)
                             {
                                 ctx.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                             }

                             return Task.CompletedTask;
                         },
                         OnRedirectToAccessDenied = (ctx) =>
                         {
                             if (ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api") && ctx.Response.StatusCode == 200)
                             {
                                 ctx.Response.StatusCode = 403;
                             }

                             return Task.CompletedTask;
                         }
                     };

                     options.EventsType = typeof(SecurityStampUpdatedCookieAuthenticationEvent);
                 });
```

Voilà, I hope I have helped at least one of you. If there is anything to change, just let me know !

## Complete code

### Startup.cs

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                    {
                        ValidIssuer = jwtModel.Issuer,
                        ValidAudience = jwtModel.Audience,
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jwtModel.Secret)),
                        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                    };
                })
                .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
                 {
                     options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
                     options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Forbidden";

                     options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents()
                     {
                         OnRedirectToLogin = (ctx) =>
                         {
                             if (ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api") && ctx.Response.StatusCode == 200)
                             {
                                 ctx.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                             }

                             return Task.CompletedTask;
                         },
                         OnRedirectToAccessDenied = (ctx) =>
                         {
                             if (ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api") && ctx.Response.StatusCode == 200)
                             {
                                 ctx.Response.StatusCode = 403;
                             }

                             return Task.CompletedTask;
                         }
                     };

                     options.EventsType = typeof(SecurityStampUpdatedCookieAuthenticationEvent);
                 });

            AuthorizationPolicy multiSchemePolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultPolicy = multiSchemePolicy;
            });
```

### AuthManager.cs

```cs
 public async Task<bool> LogInAsync(string email, string password, bool rememberMe)
        {
            await LogOutAsync();

            UserModel user = _userService.UserLogin(email, password).MapFromBLL();
            if (user is null) return false;

            user.Roles = _roleService.GetUserRoles(user.Id).Select(r => r.MapFromBLL());
            if (user.Roles is null || user.Roles.Count() == 0) return false;

            List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>()
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Email),
                new Claim("Stamp", user.SecurityStamp.ToString())
            };

            IEnumerable<Claim> roleClaims = user.Roles.Select(ur => new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, ur.Name));

            claims.AddRange(roleClaims);

            ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            AuthenticationProperties authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                AllowRefresh = true,
                ExpiresUtc = DateTime.Now.AddDays(_jwtModel.ExpirationInDays),
                IsPersistent = true,
                IssuedUtc = DateTime.Now,
            };

            ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);

            try
            {
                await _httpAccessor.HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, claimsPrincipal, authProperties);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }

        public async Task LogOutAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                await _httpAccessor.HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I am glad you were able to "fix" your problem but It is a little concerning when you are dealing with Authentication and you are plugging/changing things around without really understanding how things work under the covers. I would suggest you read more on the subject or you risk leaving doors open.