# Net Core Identity is empty after HttpContext.SignInAsnyc

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication

I am using .net core. When I use SignInManager's PasswordSignInAsync method, I can access Identity object. However, if I use HttpContext.SignInAsync method, my Identity object is empty.

```
var result = await signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, loginDTO.Password, false);

if (result.Succeeded)
{
    List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "some name"),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "some email"),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin")
    };

    ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

    ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

    var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        AllowRefresh = true,
        ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1),
        IsPersistent = true,
    };

    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal, authProperties);
}
```

My program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = "/login";
        options.Cookie.Name = "MyCookie";
    });

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

After login, I can see that I am getting a new cookie. But when I send a request to app, my identity is always empty.
HttpContext.User.Identity.Name is always null and IsAuthenticated flag is always false.

Comment: Do you have a full repo somewhere?

Comment: Can this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71050147/httpaccessor-httpcontext-signinasync-user-is-empty) help you?

Answer (score 0):

Below is a work demo, you can refer to it.

LoginModel

```
public class LoginModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name ="Username")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public bool RememberLogin { get; set; }
        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

    }
```

UserModel:

```
 public class UserModel
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Role { get; set; }
    }
```

AccountController

```
public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        //Sample Users Data, it can be fetched with the use of any ORM
        public List<UserModel> users = null;
        public AccountController()
        {
            users = new List<UserModel>();
            users.Add(new UserModel() { UserId = 1, Username = "Anoop", Password = "123", Role = "Admin" });
            users.Add(new UserModel() { UserId = 2, Username = "Other", Password = "123", Role = "User" });
        }

        public IActionResult Login(string ReturnUrl = "/")
        {
            LoginModel objLoginModel = new LoginModel();
            objLoginModel.ReturnUrl = ReturnUrl;
            return View(objLoginModel);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginModel objLoginModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = users.Where(x => x.Username == objLoginModel.UserName && x.Password == objLoginModel.Password).FirstOrDefault();
                if (user == null)
                {
                    //Add logic here to display some message to user
                    ViewBag.Message = "Invalid Credential";
                    return View(objLoginModel);
                }
                else
                {
                    //A claim is a statement about a subject by an issuer and
                    //represent attributes of the subject that are useful in the context of authentication and authorization operations.
                    var claims = new List<Claim>() {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,Convert.ToString(user.UserId)),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,user.Username),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role,user.Role),
                    new Claim("FavoriteDrink","Tea")
                    };
                    //Initialize a new instance of the ClaimsIdentity with the claims and authentication scheme
                    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                    //Initialize a new instance of the ClaimsPrincipal with ClaimsIdentity
                    var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
                    //SignInAsync is a Extension method for Sign in a principal for the specified scheme.
                    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                        principal, new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = objLoginModel.RememberLogin });

                    return LocalRedirect(objLoginModel.ReturnUrl);
                }
            }
            return View(objLoginModel);
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> LogOut() {
            //SignOutAsync is Extension method for SignOut
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            //Redirect to home page
            return LocalRedirect("/");
        }
    }
```

Login view:

```
@model LoginModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Login";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Login</h2>

<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Login">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.Message))
            {
                <span class="text-danger">
                    @ViewBag.Message
                </span>
            }
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ReturnUrl)
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="UserName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="UserName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="UserName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Password" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input asp-for="RememberLogin" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RememberLogin)
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

And add below into your _layout:

```
                         <li>
                            @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                            {
                                <a asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Logout"> Hello @User.Identity.Name! Logout</a>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <a asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login">Login</a>
                            }

                        </li>
```

result:

[image]